# Ultrapower of an ultrapower of von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, ultrapowers

Let $M$ be a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor, fix a ultrafilter $\omega$, we know the ultrapower $M^{\omega}$, is again $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor. The question is that what is the ultrapower of $M^{\omega}$, i.e., $(M^{\omega})^{\omega}$? Is it again isomorphic to $M^{\omega}$?

Comment: You seem to write "ultrafilter" (once in title and once in question) in lieu of "ultrapower". In view of an erased discussion, you might specify what you mean by ultrapower.

Comment: I mentioned 2 occurrences of the typo including one in the title. Also in a comment to an erased answer, Nik Weaver wrote "*There are actually several notions of "ultraproduct of von Neumann algebras", but since  is a $\mathrm{II}_1$ factor in this case, most likely the tracial ultrapower is meant. That is, one discards all elements of infinite norm and factors out the ideal of all sequence $(x_n)$ for which \tau(x_n^*x_n)\to 0$*". Could you confirm this is the definition you have in mind?

Comment: In an erased answer it was mentioned that the ultrapower is a saturated model. Nevertheless, the decreasing intersection of nonempty definable subsets $\{x:\tau(x)>n\}$ is empty, so I'm skeptical about this assertion (here or also in metric ultraproduct such as asymptotic cones).

Comment: I am talking about your 2nd comment as my definition.

Comment: @Desperatemathematician  I think what user YCor had in mind is that you might edit your question to include a careful definition (and perhaps a reference to a good source for where this construction is considered: e.g. a textbook, online lecture notes, or similar).  That would, in my opinion, substantially improve the question.

Comment: For fixed ultrafilter $\omega$, $M^{\omega}$ means ultraproduct of von Neumann algebras, please look at Sorin Popa's book on $\mathrm{II}_1$ factors.

Comment: @Desperatemathematician What Matt is trying to say, I think, is that if you write out the definition then (a) you may increase your own understanding, rather than just juggling abstract terminology (b) you make it easier for mathematicians who may not be specialists on vN algebras to make useful contributions

Answer (score 2):

This is an expanded version of my deleted answer and comment. Since the question does not include the definition of ultrapower and since it is not standard, I am using the definition from Ando and Haagerup, https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5457 .  That is if $M$ is a vN $II_1$ factor, and $\omega$ is an non-principal ultrafilter over natural numbers, then $M^\omega$ is obtained as follows. First take  the standard ultrapower $\Pi M/\omega$. Then take the subalgebra $A$ from that algebra consisting of sequences $(x_i)$ with $tr(x_ix_i^*)$  bounded. $A$ contains the ideal $I$ consisting of all sequences $x_i$ with $\lim tr(x_ix_i^*)=0$ (all limits are $\omega$-limits). Then $M^\omega=A/I$. With that definition $M^\omega$ is the vN analog of ultralimits (NOT ultrapowers) of metric spaces. This weird definition of "ultrapower" is consistent with the definition of ulttraproducts of Banach algebras. Probably goes back to Banach. So perhaps it is not so weird after all.

As in the paper by Kramer, Shelah, Tent, Thomas [KSTT] (there is only one paper by these 4 authors, easily found in the arXiv) one can turn every vN $II_1$ factor  into an algebraic structure with countable signature ("countable" is important) trearing trace as they treat the distance function. Then $M^\omega$ is elementarily definable in $\Pi M/\omega$. Furthermore, assuming the Continuum Hypothesis $\Pi(\Pi M/\omega)/\omega$ is isomorphic to $\Pi M/\omega$ (the proof is exactly the same as in [KSTT] using the fact that an ultraproduct is always a saturated structure). Since $M^\omega$ is elementarily definable in $\Pi M/\omega$ and $(M^\omega)^\omega$ is definable by the same first order formulas in $\Pi(\Pi M/\omega)/\omega$, we get the result. If we do not assume CH, I do not know the answer. But I refer to [KSTT] again, it may be that the answer is "no" or even "totally no" (meaning that the isomorphism almost never occurs).

Comment: I guess you might need to encode the structure (von Neumann algebra, trace) rather than just von Neumann, i.e., include the trace in the signature?

Comment: @YCor this might not be needed, because the trace on a $II_1$ factor is unique.

Comment: @NikWeaver, it is needed because it is unclear otherwise whether the ultralimit of $II_1$ factors is a $II_1$-factor. See my answer above.

Comment: @MarkSapir I think it is standard that any ultrapower of a $II_1$ factor is a $II_1$ factor. Where exactly am I supposed to be looking in your answer?

Comment: @NikWeaver, you may look at the whole answer. The KSTT approach uses conversion to algebraic structure and then the standard logic def of ultrapowers and then standard logic theorems of Keisler, Shelah and others. So one needs to define the trace and formulate all axioms of trace using a countabe signature. That is done in the case of metric function in KSTT. For the trace this is the same. I do not know if for Banach algebras (and the norm function) it was done before KSTT. Since Tarski and Banach went to the same cafe in Lvov, I would not be surprised if it was done in the 30s.

Comment: @NikWeaver including $\tau$ in the signature affect (a priori) the notion of "elementary definable".